# PyInstaller Created App WIll Launch from cmd but not from explorer

Tags: windows, wxpython, wxwidgets, pyinstaller

I am having some problems with a app we are making with wxWidget/wxPython and PyInstaller.

We have compiled the app into a single exe for windows but:

1) On some machines it will not launch at all. It doesn't generate a error or anything in the app logs. It just stops almost immediately.

2) On some machines it will launch fine from cmd but not from explorer. again, same behavior. It just stops almost immediately.  I don't even see it pop up in the process explorer.

3) On some machines it works just fine.

Are there any tips on how I can figure out what is going wrong? Is there a way to launch a exe with a debugger?

Comment: Does the app rely on another files in the same or relatively expressed directory? Did you compile it as "one file"?

Comment: Did you compile it as Windows app (no console)?

Comment: Yes, it's just one exe with no other files

Comment: I have heard that one exe may be blocked by some antivirus programs. It uses a few of hacks to get everything in one executable which may be considered malicious.

Comment: You may want to enable console and run it on machine where it does not run at all from console. That way you may see why it crashes.

Comment: Fenikso if you put that in an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Did that help? What was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you may want to look into:

1. Did you compile it as "one file"? I have heard that one exe may be blocked by some antivirus programs. It uses a few of hacks to get everything in one executable which may be considered malicious.
2. Did you compile it as Windows app (no console)? You may want to enable console and run it on machine where it does not run at all from console. That way you may see why it crashes.

Comment: It was a silly problem on our part as prt of the init and was getting swallowed. Turning on the console window showed us